# tmux not colorizing PS1 prompt

Tags: bash, osx, tmux, prompt

I recently decided to change my PS1 variable to accommodate some pretty Solarized colors for my terminal viewing pleasure. When not in a tmux session, everything is great! Rainbows, ponies, unicorns and a distinguishable prompt! Cool!

The problem is within tmux, however. I've verified that the value of PS1 is what I expect it to be and the same as it is when tmux isn't running, namely `\[\033]0;\w\007\]\[\[\]\]\u\[\]@\[\[\]\]\h\[\]:\[\]\W\[\]$ \[\]`.

All of my aliases, etc. in my .bash_profile are also functioning as expected. tmux is also displaying colors without incident, as `echo -ne "\033[1;33m hi"` behaves as expected as does `gls --color`.

The current relevant line in my .bash_profile is `export PS1="\[\033]0;\w\007\]\[\[\]\]\u\[\]@\[\[\]\]\h\[\]:\[\]\W\[\]$ \[\]"`, although originally I was sourcing a script located in a .bash_prompt file to handle some conditionals, etc. I tried reverting to the simpler version.

Executing `bash` will cause the prompt to colorize, but must be done in each pane. `export PS1=[that long string I've already posted]` will not.

My .tmux.conf is as follows:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l /usr/local/bin/bash"
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Relevant portions of .bash_profile:

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
if which tmux >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    test -z "$TMUX" && (tmux attach || tmux new-session)
fi
```

I'm using macOS Sierra, iTerm 2, I've tried both the current homebrew version of bash and the system bash (it's currently using the homebrew), tmux 2.4.

I also placed `touch testing_touch_from_bash_profile` in my .bash_profile while in a tmux session with two panes, killed one pane, opened a pane and verified that the file was in fact created.

`echo $TERM` returns `xterm-256color`.

I've ensured that when exiting tmux to test settings changes that I've exited tmux and that no tmux process is currently running on the system via `ps -ax | grep tmux`.

Oddly, sourcing the .bash_prompt script also changes the color so long as I do it within each tmux pane.

I've looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005966/tmux-prompt-not-following-normal-bash-prompt-ps1-w and tried adding the --login flag after the bash call in the first line of my .tmux.conf. Launching tmux with `tmux new bash` will cause the first pane to colorize, but subsequent panes will not.

The $PS1 variable is being honored for seemingly all aspects except colorizing any of the fields.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try single quotes

Comment: The `PS1` setting you posted doesn't have any command to change colors. Post an actual setting that does work outside tmux. Also, you should set `PS1` in `.bashrc`, not in `.bash_profile`: `.bash_profile` might not get executed at all, and the settings might be overridden later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PS1 also gives me black and white output.

However switching back to mine gives me color, so you should be able to figure out the different, I use

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\033[01;31m\]\t \[\033[01;32m\]durrantm \[\033[02;36m\]\h \[\033[01;34m\]`pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/\).*\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}\)/\{0,1\}#\1_\2#g"` \[\033[00;33m\]$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$
```

git_branch is a bash function I have which is:

```
git_branch () { 
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}
```

#### Yours vs. Mine:

[image]

This works the same on OSX and Ubuntu

Comment: -1 This in fact dosent give him an answer to the question posted but instead show him that there is an error in his example. This should be handled has a comment rather that an "answer" IMHO

Answer (score 67):

On my machine the solution is to add

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

to `~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution. Thank you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO. Sourcing .bashrc in each sub shell is both cumbersome and not needed. I do beleive that the point behind this is that tmux default to a $TERM='tmux' which is not handled by termcap as a "color capable shell"

Comment: For me, `xterm-256color` works but disables the home and end keyboard keys. `screen-256color` works too without the keyboard problem on Debian.

Answer (score 31):

My solution to this problem was setting

`force_color_prompt=yes`

in my `.bashrc`. Now my tmux prompt has color.

Comment: Not sure why this behaves differently in tmux to outside of it, but this did the trick for me too.

Comment: I th ink you should specify this: what you have to do is run the command `tmux` , and then inside a tmux session run `source ~/.bashrc` . You need to do that in each panel.

Comment: Thanks, this work for me also on Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-terminal.

Comment: For those wondering why this works, by default tmux has $TERM set to 'screen', while when not using tmux $TERM is usually set to something like 'xterm-256color' (see [Siyuan's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577104/150697)). The default .bashrc only sets a colored prompt if $TERM is set to xterm-color or ends in -256color; since 'screen' does not the colored prompt gets turned off.

Answer (score 1):

#### Change $TERM to xterm-256color

No color:

```
$ echo $TERM                                              
screen
```

With color:

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

Add this to your dotfile.

#### Remarks

This may not be the OPs situation but in case anyone else has landed on this page with this situation I'm hoping it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working on Ubuntu 20.04.

While [Panki's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493472/390383) worked for me, I found myself always specifying `source ~/.bashrc` whenever I logged into **Tmux** shell following [evaristegd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/324019/evaristegd)'s comment.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Firstly, create a file called `.tmux` in the home directory of your machine, which is `~/.tmux.conf`.

Next, put in the configuration that you want to use for **Tmux** inside it and save it. For me the configuration I needed was the same as the **GNU screen** package that comes default with Ubuntu uses, so I copied the content of the `~/.bashrc` file into the `~/.tmux.conf` file. This way if I have to edit any of the configurations for **Tmux**, I wouldn't tamper with the one for the **GNU screen**.

**Note**: You could skip this step and just use the `~/.bashrc` file if you do not care for separation of concerns.

Next, add the file to either the `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` file. It should be added at the bottom of the file:

```
source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
```

OR

```
source "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Here's an example:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
```

**Note**: The `~/.bash_profile` file takes the first precedence, then the `~/.bash_login` file as the second precedence, and then the `~/.profile` file as the last precedence.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**